# Which development board/kit supports camera parallel interface?

Tags: camera, vga

I need to interface qvga camera sensor which has parallel interface so, I am looking for any suitable development kit/board for 'vga/qvga camera parallel interface' which supports less complexity in hardware/software.

Please suggest if any. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, hardware & software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks. Is there any other stack exchange for 'hw/sw recommendations'?